# If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, does $u_n^+ \rightharpoonup u^+$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain.

If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, does $u_n^+ \rightharpoonup u^+$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ where $u_n^+ = \max(0,u_n)$.

Note all convergences are weak.

My guess is no though I hope the answer is yes. I'm not sure at all how to prove it.

Comment: it seems that $\Omega=(0,2\pi)$, $u_n=\sin nx$, $u=0$ is a counterexample

Comment: Take the sequence $(r_n)$ of Rademacher functions in $L_2[0,1]$. they converge weakly to $0$. But $\int_0^1 1\cdot r_n^+ =1/2$ for each $n$. (Same as above, almost.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments: the answer is negative, and functions like $\sin nx$ or Rademacher functions $r_n$ provide counterexamples. They converge weakly to $0$, but the integral of the positive part does not tend to $0$.